# option value alternatives in html

Tags: html, html-select

I have a list of over a thousand names in my MySQL database table. I need to select names from it. I am currently using an "option value" element via html to select a name, but obviously this is not effective as the list is too long. What other ways can I use to select a name. Thanks guys

Comment: do you mean you have a `<select>` in your html with over thousand `<option>` ? can you use autocomplete?

Comment: You could consider using a search / filters to narrow the results based on a little user input, but I think this is probably more suited to UX: http://ux.stackexchange.com

Comment: You can apply dropdown list with auto-suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the example of [loading data using Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#data). Ultimately it all depends on how you want/need the user interface to look and feel.

Answer (score 0):

You can have two dropdown list, one for range (for name - starts with..) - say - A to D, E to p, Q to W, W to Z... kind of...
You can populate the second dropdown list based on the item selected in the first dropdown..

Answer (score 0):

HTML has you covered.

Use a filterable [`<datalist>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist):

```js
const data =['Afghanistan','Åland Islands','Albania','Algeria','American Samoa','AndorrA','Angola','Anguilla','Antarctica','Antigua and Barbuda','Argentina','Armenia','Aruba','Australia','Austria','Azerbaijan','Bahamas','Bahrain','Bangladesh','Barbados','Belarus','Belgium','Belize','Benin','Bermuda','Bhutan','Bolivia','Bosnia and Herzegovina','Botswana','Bouvet Island','Brazil','British Indian Ocean Territory','Brunei Darussalam','Bulgaria','Burkina Faso','Burundi','Cambodia','Cameroon','Canada','Cape Verde','Cayman Islands','Central African Republic','Chad','Chile','China','Christmas Island','Cocos (Keeling) Islands','Colombia','Comoros','Congo','Congo, The Democratic Republic of the','Cook Islands','Costa Rica','Cote D\'Ivoire','Croatia','Cuba','Cyprus','Czech Republic','Denmark','Djibouti','Dominica','Dominican Republic','Ecuador','Egypt','El Salvador','Equatorial Guinea','Eritrea','Estonia','Ethiopia','Falkland Islands (Malvinas)','Faroe Islands','Fiji','Finland','France','French Guiana','French Polynesia','French Southern Territories','Gabon','Gambia','Georgia','Germany','Ghana','Gibraltar','Greece','Greenland','Grenada','Guadeloupe','Guam','Guatemala','Guernsey','Guinea','Guinea-Bissau','Guyana','Haiti','Heard Island and Mcdonald Islands','Holy See (Vatican City State)','Honduras','Hong Kong','Hungary','Iceland','India','Indonesia','Iran, Islamic Republic Of','Iraq','Ireland','Isle of Man','Israel','Italy','Jamaica','Japan','Jersey','Jordan','Kazakhstan','Kenya','Kiribati','Korea, Democratic People\'S Republic of','Korea, Republic of','Kuwait','Kyrgyzstan','Lao People\'S Democratic Republic','Latvia','Lebanon','Lesotho','Liberia','Libyan Arab Jamahiriya','Liechtenstein','Lithuania','Luxembourg','Macao','Macedonia, The Former Yugoslav Republic of','Madagascar','Malawi','Malaysia','Maldives','Mali','Malta','Marshall Islands','Martinique','Mauritania','Mauritius','Mayotte','Mexico','Micronesia, Federated States of','Moldova, Republic of','Monaco','Mongolia','Montserrat','Morocco','Mozambique','Myanmar','Namibia','Nauru','Nepal','Netherlands','Netherlands Antilles','New Caledonia','New Zealand','Nicaragua','Niger','Nigeria','Niue','Norfolk Island','Northern Mariana Islands','Norway','Oman','Pakistan','Palau','Palestinian Territory, Occupied','Panama','Papua New Guinea','Paraguay','Peru','Philippines','Pitcairn','Poland','Portugal','Puerto Rico','Qatar','Reunion','Romania','Russian Federation','RWANDA','Saint Helena','Saint Kitts and Nevis','Saint Lucia','Saint Pierre and Miquelon','Saint Vincent and the Grenadines','Samoa','San Marino','Sao Tome and Principe','Saudi Arabia','Senegal','Serbia and Montenegro','Seychelles','Sierra Leone','Singapore','Slovakia','Slovenia','Solomon Islands','Somalia','South Africa','South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands','Spain','Sri Lanka','Sudan','Suriname','Svalbard and Jan Mayen','Swaziland','Sweden','Switzerland','Syrian Arab Republic','Taiwan, Province of China','Tajikistan','Tanzania, United Republic of','Thailand','Timor-Leste','Togo','Tokelau','Tonga','Trinidad and Tobago','Tunisia','Turkey','Turkmenistan','Turks and Caicos Islands','Tuvalu','Uganda','Ukraine','United Arab Emirates','United Kingdom','United States','United States Minor Outlying Islands','Uruguay','Uzbekistan','Vanuatu','Venezuela','Viet Nam','Virgin Islands, British','Virgin Islands, U.S.','Wallis and Futuna','Western Sahara','Yemen','Zambia','Zimbabwe']

countries.append(...data.map(country => Object.assign(document.createElement('option'), { value: country })))
```

```html
<label for="country-choice">Choose a country:</label>
<input list="countries" id="country-choice" name="country-choice" />

<datalist id="countries"></datalist>
```